# How to get Direct Messages from Twitter account

Tags: ios, xcode, api, twitter

Can anyone describe how to get twitter Direct Messages, everyone says enable application read, write, Direct message access from account, I have enable all from twitter dev. account but still i don't know how to get direct messages from my twitter account, please explain with example.

Thanks in advance,